# Custom Shipping Method - Please specify a shipping method

Tags: php, magento2, checkout

I'm working on a custom shipping method and I've been getting exception each times I try to place an order with my method ("Please specify a shipping method").

I tried with the Magento 2 Flat Rate method and it worked.

I found that in Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteValidator.php on line 52, the `getShippingMethod()` returned nothing because that function :

```
public function getShippingMethod()
{
    return $this->getData('shipping_method');
}
```

in Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php returned nothing.

Just in case my code was wrong, I also tried with this custom shipping method (I followed this tutorial to create the method) http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/create-custom-shipping-module-in-magento-2/ (just activate the module and tried to place an order with that method) but I'm facing the same issue.

Does someone know how I can resolve this issue ?
Thanks.

Here is my Model/Carrier/method.php :

```
class Method extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
protected $_logger;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_code = 'coursierprive_transport';

/**
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_isFixed = true;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
 */
protected $_rateResultFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
 */
protected $_rateMethodFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
    $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
}

/**
 * @param RateRequest $request
 * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
 */
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active'))
        return (false);

    if ($request->getAllItems())
    {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item)
        {
            // Some stuff used to check dimensions, weight, post code... etc
        }
    }
    if (//some tests)
        return (false);

    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    $shippingPrice = 5.5;

    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes())
        $shippingPrice = 0;

    $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
    $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

    $result->append($method);

    return ($result);
}

/**
 * Get allowed shipping methods
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return (['coursierprive_transport' => $this->getConfigData('name')]);
}
}
```

Here is my Config.xml :

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <coursierprive_transport>
                <active>1</active>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <price>5.5</price>
                <model>CoursierPrive\Transport\Model\Carrier\Method</model>
                <name>Express</name>
                <title>Coursier Privé</title>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is not available. To use this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            </coursierprive_transport>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

I think that I know what messed up. I suppose there is a size limit for the method name and my first name contained too many chars.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the code to something short like:

```
protected $_code = 'couriertransport';
```

I am not sure if this is the issue but doing so fixed the issue:
https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-custom-shipping

Answer (score 0):

My case : protected $_code = 'effectconnect_shipment';
=> so full code must be 'effectconnect_shipment_effectconnect_shipment'
I checked the length of this code is only 40 so rename it to $_code = 'effectconnect'; and it work !!!